# change wordpress default post date field

Tags: php, wordpress

I searched over the internet about this but didn't find correct solution. Is this possible to change wordpress default date field ? I'm asking about the publish date .. that I can set from post page.

Current WordPress date field look like:

[image: Default date option]

I want to make it in a one text field like:

[image: Want like this]

Is that possible to change the date format??

Thanks
Hope someone help.

Comment: Why would you want to change it? Its part of wordpress interface

Comment: I know.. Its a part of wordpress interface. Is that possible do it with custom meta field?

Comment: Actually I don't understand I how use custom meta field for date.. actually I don't want to create another date field .. I want to manipulate original post date.. is that possible with custom post meta field? @SunilGehlot

Comment: you can modify that date field, but its the worst idea, and you need to dig into wordpress core file, I don't get the point of modifying it, for what purpose? just create a custom field/custom metabox if you want a custom date field

Comment: @silver is that possible with custom post meta field that will use as post date?  so my sort orderby=date & others date option will work?